# Ubuntu 22.04: USB Keeps Disconnecting and Reconnecting with 5-1 usb hub

Tags: usb, 22.04, hardware, logs

For some time now, I have been experiencing issues with my USB input (mouse, keyboard) devices that are connected through a USB hub. These devices reconnect themselves after a certain period, approximately one minute. Upon reconnection, the devices are unavailable for a few seconds. Initially, I thought it might have something to do with auto-suspend for USB devices. However, disabling auto-suspend did not resolve the problem.

I'm using a 5-in-1 USB-C hub from Anker, featuring Power Delivery and HDMI. PD and HDMI work flawlessly. When I connect the USB devices directly to my laptop, it works perfectly.

I am using an AMD Ryzen Lenovo ThinkPad (T14 gen3).

The output of my hardware log only shows the following same message:

```
11:52:35 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.0112: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:52:34 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:52:34 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.0110: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:52:34 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:52:33 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:52:33 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:50:00 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.010E: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:49:59 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:49:59 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.010C: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:49:59 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:49:58 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:49:58 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:49:46 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.010A: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:49:45 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:49:45 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.0108: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:49:45 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:49:44 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:49:44 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:46:51 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.0106: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:46:51 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:46:51 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.0104: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:46:51 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:46:50 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:46:50 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:44:13 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.0102: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:44:13 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:44:13 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.0100: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:44:13 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:44:12 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:44:12 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:43:37 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.00FE: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:43:37 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:43:36 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.00FC: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:43:36 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:43:35 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:43:35 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:43:28 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.00FA: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:43:28 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:43:28 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.00F8: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:43:27 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:43:26 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:43:26 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:42:54 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.00F6: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:42:54 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:42:54 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.00F4: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
11:42:54 kernel: usb 9-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
11:42:53 kernel: hub 9-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
11:42:53 kernel: usb 9-1: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
11:41:55 kernel: hid-generic 0003:045E:082E.00F2: hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Ergonomic Mouse] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.4/input1
11:41:55 kernel: usb 9-1.4: SerialNumber: 523987194211
11:41:55 kernel: microsoft 0003:045E:0750.00F0: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600] on usb-0000:05:00.4-1.3/input1
```

I can't find any solution for the problem. May some one can help me. Thank you.